# Linux equivalent in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I am writing Tcl scripts, just checking if the following Linux command can be written using Tcl instead.

```
 csplit --digits=3 --quiet --prefix=$abc $inputfile /~$position/
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably, but running `csplit` in a subprocess seems the easiest method offhand. Why work harder than you have to?

Comment: Thank you Donal Fellows, sounds right and that's what I wanted to hear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but [tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/index.html) may has something to get you started, maybe [textutil::split](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil_split.html)?

Comment: Thanks Rolazaro Azeveires, I will take a look.